# How to recursively download a whole directory in one run via FTP

Tags: ftp, file-copy, recursive

I am trying to migrate a folder from one server to another, using FTP on Linux via SSH. I am not finding a command to download all the masses at once. The Commands that I found only download the files inside the folders but the subfolders don't download together

I'm using this command down

```
ftp> prompt [Enter]

ftp> mget *
```

Which Command can I use to also download the subfolders? I've looked in several more unsuccessfully

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113886/how-to-recursively-download-a-folder-via-ftp-on-linux

Comment: If you want a GUI solution, look into **Filezilla**.

Comment: also `wget -m/-r`